# SQL - Adding Counts next to Customers & Order Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to place a resetting count of orders next to customers and order dates, but not sure what the right way to approach it would be.

The table would be customer ID, order date, and what order number it was for the customer (order 1 for the customer, order 2 for the customer, etc) with date repeating if they made two orders on the same date.

Right now the data looks like the following using a simple "order / group by"

```
| CustomerID  |  OrderNumber   |          Date           |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 0           |   1            | 2010-12-17 00:00:00.000 |
| 0           |   2            | 2011-08-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 0           |   3            | 2011-08-29 00:00:00.000 |
| 0           |   4            | 2011-08-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 1           |   5            | 2007-10-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 1           |   6            | 2007-10-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 2           |   7            | 2004-12-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 2           |   8            | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 |
| 2           |   9            | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 |
| 3           |   10           | 2004-12-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 3           |   11           | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 |
| 3           |   12           | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make it look like this, I can get the first three columns but not the third to reset after each customer number

```
| CustomerID  |  OrderNumber   |       Date              | Order Count |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0           |   1            | 2010-12-17 00:00:00.000 | 1           |
| 0           |   2            | 2011-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 2           |
| 0           |   3            | 2011-08-29 00:00:00.000 | 3           |
| 0           |   4            | 2011-08-31 00:00:00.000 | 4           |
| 1           |   5            | 2007-10-23 00:00:00.000 | 1           |
| 1           |   6            | 2007-10-23 00:00:00.000 | 2           |
| 2           |   7            | 2004-12-09 00:00:00.000 | 1           |
| 2           |   8            | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 | 2           |
| 2           |   9            | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 | 3           |
| 3           |   10           | 2004-12-09 00:00:00.000 | 1           |
| 3           |   11           | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 | 2           |
| 3           |   12           | 2011-08-24 00:00:00.000 | 3           |
| 3           |   13           | 2011-09-24 00:00:00.000 | 4           |
| 3           |   14           | 2013-08-24 00:00:00.000 | 5           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here's where I'm at so far

```
SELECT        CustomerID, OrderNumber, Date
FROM            dbo.Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderNumber, Date
order by CustomerID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
     CustomerID
    ,OrderNumber
    ,[Date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderNumber) AS OrderCount
FROM dbo.orders
;
```

Comment: @3BK, You speed with keyboard :)

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader You're, like, the fiftieth person to tell me that today.  :) As I said to the last guy, typing fast is one of my few redeeming qualities!

Comment: You deserve, +1 from me, go on .. :)

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Thank you :) Much appreciated.